# Understanding variance formula

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, descriptive-statistics

I know that $var(X)=E[(X-E(X))^2]$ .

However, I am confused because it seems to me that this definition is recursive in that the expected value of the square is itself a function of an expected value. Can anyone please clarify this?

Comment: The expected value $E(X)$ is a number. It's a constant. It has a value that you can compute from the distribution of $X$. Call it $\mu=E(X)$. Now you can compute  $E[(X-\mu)^2]$ since $(X-\mu)^2$ is a random variable. There is nothing really recursive.

Comment: In my opinion there is a logical issue here. You expect a definition to be recursive if it depends on itself. Now you want to define the variance of a random variable. The definition would be recursive if the variance of a r.v. appeared on the right member in your definition. This is not the case. Just expected values appear on the right and the expectation value of a r.v. is defined independently.

Answer (score 0):

Variance measures spread. The formula says that variance is the averaged squared distance from the mean. For small examples, I have my students do the following:

Take a data set and find its mean. Then, find how far away, plus or minus, each observation is from the mean (i.e., the deviations). Now square those distances and find that average.